# NSMutableSet not adding objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've got the following code where program is an NSArray with NSNumber objects and NSString objects. After the code executes, even though I've confirmed that the second if condition is satisfied at at least once (when [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] is true), the NSMutableSet variables is completely empty.

```
NSMutableSet *variables;
if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (id obj in program) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            [variables addObject:obj];
        }
    }
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not creating a NSMutableSet

```
NSMutableSet *variables = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

//release later if not ARC enabled
```

or more convenient

```
NSMutableSet *variables = [NSMutableSet set];
```

<sub>(thanks to dreamlax for reminding me)</sub>

Comment: Make sure you `release` that afterwards too, or alternatively use `[NSMutableSet set]`.

Comment: That `variables` is initialized to nil means that ARC is in use, which means you can't `release`.

Comment: well duh! thanks ... guess sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes.

Comment: @StevenFisher: It may have been placed conveniently on the stack for it to be `nil` too, but probably more likely that ARC is enabled.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. :) I was thinking "most likely" but should have been specific. Thanks for the clarification for future readers.